# Proving a function is not uniformly continuous.

Tags: analysis, continuity

I am using the definition:

$(∃ε > 0)(∀n ∈ N)(∃ x_n, y_n ∈ (0,1])[(|x_n − y_n| < δ_n =1/n) ∧ (|f(x_n) − f(y_n)| ≥ ε)]$

to prove that $1/x^2$ is not uniformly continuous.

In the solution I am given, epsilon is chosen as 1 and $x_n=1/n$ and $y_n=1/(2n)$. I see that this is a solution, however, I don't get why these 3 values are chosen. Generally, how does one go about picking epsilon, $x_n$ and $y_n$?

Comment: I don't have the time for a proper answer right now, but here is a minor point: If it looks like any $\varepsilon$ might do, then picking $\varepsilon=1$ seems the least arbitrary choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function goes to infinity at the origin, it seems sort of obvious that you can find $x$ and $y$ arbitrarily close to $0$ with $f(y)\ge f(x)+1$. Once you see that, and given the simple nature of *this* function, we might as well make that into an equality! So pick $x_n$ with $f(x_n)=n$ and let $y_n=x_{n+1}$, and you're done. In this case, that means $x_n=1/\sqrt{n}$.

More generally, since $f(x)\to\infty$ when $x\to0$ and $f$ is continuous, you can use the intermediate value theorem to prove the existence of $x_n$ solving $f(x_n)=n$ (at least when $n$ is large enough). So now you have a proof that works on a large class of functions, not just the one given.

How I thought of this: I thought of getting function values (at least) one apart, which led me to visualize the horizontal lines $y=1$, $y=2$, $y=3$, … together with the graph of $f$. Consider the intersection points, and the proof writes itself.